# My Android app text size is changing if user decrease or increase size from mobile setting

Tags: android, android-webview, android-debug

I have website using  Webview I created Android application.  I want the **text size  same as website in android application.** And text size should not change if user increase or decrease text size from mobile setting.

Answer (score 0):

This will force the App to use the Phone's 'default' text size. Even if the user goes into Phone Settings and changes the font size, it will stay default in the App..

```
Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();
configuration.fontScale = 1.0f;
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
metrics.scaledDensity = configuration.fontScale * metrics.density;
getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
```

Comment: I tried but it is not working. On android browser its showing correct size but not in App

Answer (score 0):

Try to use dp instead of sp.
If you already use dp, give us the xml code of an Activity with TextView to find out where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

None of the previous answers worked for me, on Android 8.1 (API 27). Here's what worked: Add the following code to your activity:

Kotlin Code:

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {

val newOverride = Configuration(newBase?.resources?.configuration)
newOverride.fontScale = 1.0f
applyOverrideConfiguration(newOverride)

super.attachBaseContext(newBase)}
```

Java Code:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {

final Configuration override = new Configuration(newBase.getResources().getConfiguration());
override.fontScale = 1.0f;
applyOverrideConfiguration(override);

super.attachBaseContext(newBase);}
```

You don't need to change your AndroidManifest.xml.